# Torch - How to change tensor type?

Tags: lua, torch

I created a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 3.

```
th> y = torch.randperm(3 );
th> y
 3
 2
 1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3]
```

Now, I want to convert `y` to a `Torch.LongTensor`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`y = y.long()` does the job. There are similar methods for other data types, such as `int`, `char`, `float` and `byte`.

You can check different dtypes [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html).

Comment: There's a typo. Of course, una_dinosauria means y.long()

Comment: @OlivierRoche This post referred originally to lua torch, where `y:long()` was valid syntax. I guess in the last few years "torch" has come to mean "pytorch"

Answer (score 41):

use `.to` method of torch as follows:

```
y = y.to(torch.long)
```

More details about torch tensor **type/ops** can be found here

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

Answer (score 23):

For pytorch users, because searching for change tensor type in pytorch in google brings to this page, you can do:

```
y = y.type(torch.LongTensor)
```